# Edit JavaFx TableView cell with TextField in different columns

Tags: javafx, tableview, textfield, tablecell, tablecolumn

I have TableView which contain 3 columns, Two of them are edit with TextFields to permit user enter data into them but when I retrieve items from the table it return what is not into the TextFields like in image not return the correct numbers in the cells

[Table with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHofv.png)

this is my code:

Edit I found that the problem in my ObservableList (data) I add action to the TextField to update data with new value but how to make code update different rows because it update the value with the last value in the TextField and get rid of to press ENTER to get the whole value in the TxtField because it ignore the last char for example if enter "30" in the TxtField I get "3" not "30"

```
    productQuantity.setCellFactory(new Callback <TableColumn, TableCell> ()
    {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn param)
        {
            return new TableCell()
            {
                private TextField txtProductQuantity;

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty)
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if(!empty)
                    {
                        setGraphic(getTextField());
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }

                public TextField getTextField()
                {
                    if(txtProductQuantity == null)
                    {
                        txtProductQuantity = new TextField();

                        txtProductQuantity.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);

                        txtPurchaseItemPrice.setOnKeyPressed(e ->
                        {
                            data.get(0).setPurchaseItemPrice(txtPurchaseItemPrice.getText());
                        });
                    }

                    return txtProductQuantity;
                }
            };
        }
    });
    productQuantity.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<ProductOpeningBalance, String>> ()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<ProductOpeningBalance, String> t)
        {
            ((ProductOpeningBalance)        
                t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())
            ).setProductQuantity(t.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```

the code to retrieve data from the table

```
    size = tableProductOpeningBalance.getItems().size();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    System.out.println(tableProductOpeningBalance.getItems().get(i).getPurchaseItemPrice());
    }
```

please help?

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: a) no need to re-invent the wheel, use TextFieldTableCell b) with a proper (for fx) designed data object- expose properties to use in valueFactory -, there's no need for a commitHandler

Comment: I didn't use TextFieldTableCell because I need to put the whole TextField in the TableView cell with some additional properties, can I use any solution in this case?

Comment: And can pass the TextField when call setCellFactory instead of create it inside the method